# Encrypted local data with Flex Mobile

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I want to make a mobile app using Flex:

Here are the prereqs for my question:

I need to save images to be displayed locally, say SD card.
I need to encrypt them so that they can't be downloaded off the card.

The reason being is that after the app is installed, I want the content accessible whether the device has an internet/data connection or not - but the content is also the value of the application and is subject to copyright. I don't want the data to be easily accessed and copied.

Everything I've looked at, since I'm new to Flex, suggests this isn't possible:

ie. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to prevent access to the images that your app saves?

Comment: What is the copyright issue; and how does encrypting the files saved to disk solve it?

Comment: Well, I own the copyright to the material, which is the value of the app, since it's a handbook. The value of the app is also in the fact that you don't need to be able to connect to the internet. Therefore, I'd like to keep the data encrypted on the device.

Comment: Well, then why not embed the images in the app instead of storing them externally?

Answer (score 1):

You should just store your 'copyrighted' material to an [encrypted SQLite database](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/encrypted_database.html).